# How to separate specific list items with "+" and add to formula?

Tags: r, formula

I am trying to generate a formula using dataframe column names of the following format:

```
d ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4
```

From the following sample dataset:

```
a = c(1,2,3)
b = c(2,4,6)
c = c(1,3,5)
d = c(9,8,7)
x1 = c(1,2,3)
x2 = c(2,4,6)
x3 = c(1,3,5)
x4 = c(9,8,7)

df = data.frame(a,b,c,d,x1,x2,x3,x4)
```

---

As for what I have tried already:

I know that I can subset only the columns I need using the following approach

```
predictors = names(df[5:8])
response = names(df[4])
```

Although, my efforts to try and include these into a formula have failed

---

How can I assemble the predictors and the response variables into the following format:

```
d ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4
```

I ultimately want to input this formula into a [randomForest](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can avoid the entire problem by using the default method of `randomForest` (rather than the formula method):

```
randomForest(df[5:8], df[[4]])
```

or in terms of `predictors` and `response` defined in the question:

```
randomForest(df[predictors], df[[response]])
```

As mentioned in the *Note* section of the [randomForest help file](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/randomForest/docs/randomForest) the default method used here has the additional advantage of better performance than the formula method.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
reformulate(predictors,response=response)
```